# Flask-sqlalchemy + pymssql prevent SQL injections from Stored Procedure params

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, sql-injection, pymssql

I have the next route that works perfectly fine:

```
@home_app.route('/<id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home(id):
    query = "DECLARE @return_value int, @EXIST bit EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[SP_CHECK_ID] @ID = N'" + id +"', @EXIST = @EXIST OUTPUT SELECT @EXIST as N'@EXIST'"
    result = db.session.execute(query, bind=db.get_engine(app, 'second_db'))
    exist = []
    for row in result:
        exist.append(row['@EXIST'])
    return "Exist? " + str(row['@EXIST'])
```

The problem is that it could be vulnerable to SQL injection due the param. In order to fix that, I've tried:

```
query = """
        DECLARE @return_value int, @EXIST bit
        EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[SP_CHECK_ID] @ID = N':id',
        @EXIST = @EXIST OUTPUT
        SELECT @EXIST as N'@EXIST'
        """
result = db.session.execute(query, {'id': id}, bind=db.get_engine(app, 'second_db'))
```

But I got an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pymssql.ProgrammingError) (102, b"Incorrect syntax near '179'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n") [SQL: "DECLARE @return_value int, @EXIST bit EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[SP_CHECK_ID] @ID = N'%(id)s', @EXIST = @EXIST OUTPUT SELECT @EXIST as N'@EXIST'"] [parameters: {'id': '179'}]
```

I've tried with other ways:

```
query = """
        DECLARE @return_value int, @EXIST bit
        EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[SP_CHECK_ID] @ID = N'%s',
        @EXIST = @EXIST OUTPUT
        SELECT @EXIST as N'@EXIST'
        """
result = db.session.execute(query, id, bind=db.get_engine(app, 'second_db'))
```

But I got:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

I tried too with

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
query = text(...)
```

and using ? instead of %s, but I got the same errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the benefits of using placeholders is that you do not need to – and should not – quote manually. So when you include

```
""" ... N':id' ... """
```

in your query that might render as

```
""" ... N''179'' ... """
```

or such, depending on your argument's type etc. The fix is then to remove the quotes and let SQLAlchemy/the DB-API driver handle all that:

```
query = """
        DECLARE @return_value int, @EXIST bit
        EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[SP_CHECK_ID] @ID = :id,
        @EXIST = @EXIST OUTPUT
        SELECT @EXIST as N'@EXIST'
        """
result = db.session.execute(
    query, {'id': id},
    bind=db.get_engine(app, 'second_db'))
```

The named placeholder style is a backend-neutral SQLAlchemy abstraction provided by the [`text()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) construct. [`Session.execute()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.execute) implicitly wraps your textual SQL, if you've omitted it. `%s`, `?` etc. are DP-API specific placeholder styles. [pymssql](http://pymssql.org/en/stable/ref/pymssql.html#pymssql.Cursor.execute) would seem to use the percent style.